# map multiple model attributes to a ModelAndView in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, one-to-many, modelattribute

I have tried to implement one-to-many association using spring and hibernate. But I cant implement two model attributes using a single form. How to map two model attributes in a single form.

My controller code is,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminTestPage(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, @ModelAttribute("education")Education education, BindingResult result, ModelMap map, Model model) {



        return new ModelAndView("test","command",new Employee());
}
```

my jsp form is,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<%@taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="saveEmp">  
        <table >  
          <tr>
          <td>Employee Name : </td> 
          <td><form:input path="empName"  /></td>
         </tr>  
         <tr>  
          <td>Address :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="empAddress" /></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>  
          <td>Salary :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="salary" /></td>
         </tr>      
         <tr>  
          <td>Salary :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="qualification" /></td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>  
          <td>Salary :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="stream" /></td>
         </tr>  

         <tr>  
          <td>Age :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="empAge" />
          <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/></td>
         </tr>                       
         <tr>  
          <td> </td>  
          <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>  
         </tr>  
        </table>  
       </form:form>  
</body>
</html>
```

My employee.java entity code is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Integer empId;

    @Column
    private String empName;


    @Column
    private String empAddress;

    @Column
    private Long salary;

    @Column
    private Integer empAge;

    @Transient
    private List<Education> education;
    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }

    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getEmpAge() {
        return empAge;
    }

    public void setEmpAge(Integer empAge) {
        this.empAge = empAge;
    }

    public List<Education> getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public void setEducation(List<Education> education) {
        this.education = education;
    }







}
```

Education.java entity is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Education")
public class Education{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_contacts", sequenceName = "seq_contacts")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq_contacts")
    private int eduID;

    @Column
    private String qualification;

    @Column
    private String stream;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="empId")
    private Employee employee;
public Education(){

    }

    public Education(int eduID, String qualification,String stream, Employee employee )
    {
        super();
        this.eduID = eduID;
        this.qualification = qualification;
        this.stream=stream;
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public int getEduID() {
        return eduID;
    }

    public void setEduID(int eduID) {
        this.eduID = eduID;
    }

    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }

    public void setQualification(String qualification) {
        this.qualification = qualification;
    }

    public String getStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    public void setStream(String stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
```

Error is,

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'qualification' of bean class [com.java.web.model.Employee]: Bean property 'qualification' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:708)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:218)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.test_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f4(test_jsp.java:328)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.test_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(test_jsp.java:169)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

Please any one help me to solve this.

Comment: Take a look at the first line in  your error messages:  `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'qualification' of bean class [com.java.web.model.Employee]: Bean property 'qualification' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?` try to fix this first, then see what you come up with.

Comment: the reason of that error is return new ModelAndView("test","command",new Employee()); this line. My actuall question is also this, how to map two entities in a form. Here qualification is in education.java entity